# SAS: Naming a table based on a cell value

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have an Excel file that always has the same name but the contents of the table changes. I am looking to write a code that names the table based on the value in one of the cells.

For example:

If cell A3 equals "Employment Information", I want the table to be named "Jobs".
If cell A3 equals "Inflation Information", I want the table to be named "Currency".

etc.

I want to define ONE macro (i.e. `%table(filename,cell)`), or ONE loop of if then else statements to achieve this. Unfortunately, I can't seem to wrap my head around this logically. If someone with experience in SAS could help me out that would be awesome. I will edit my question soon to include some codes that I have already tried but which have failed to get the job done.

Comment: "name a table" <- what does this mean specifically?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more specific. Perhaps I should have called it table creation. When a table or datasheet is created, it has a name. 

Ie. Create table ______ as... or Data ______ set....;

Does that make sense now?

Comment: A3 is a Excel reference. How would you find that value when reading the actual SAS dataset that you have created?  What variable name represents column A?  How will you know which observation to use?

Comment: Perhaps it makes a bit more sense, but you need to include the promised code and examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the data to find the content. You could then create a macro variable to make it easy to rename the dataset using PROC DATASETS.

Let's assume you have converted the Excel sheet into a dataset named WORK.HAVE.  Let's also assume that you know what variable contains the data from column A, let's call that variable A. Is there anything in the data that makes it possible to tell which observation is the one to use?  For now let's just assume that by A3 you mean the second observation since the first row of the sheet should have the variable names.

So in that case you want something like this:

```
%let newname=have;
data _null_;
  set have (firstobs=2);
  if A="Employment Information" then call symputx('newname','Jobs');
  else if A="Inflation Information" then call symputx('newname','Currency');
  stop;
run;
proc datasets nolist lib=work;
  change have=&newname;
  run;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I used what you provided as a framework and was able to get it to work. I appreciate the help!